# setting asp.net5 project output folder

Tags: asp.net-core

In an asp.net5 solution with multiple .net 4.51 projects and one asp.net5 web project

how do I set each project's output folder so all libraries can be 
picked up correctly?

asp.net5 project uses full .net5 library.

i am honestly fed up and tired of stackoverflow and will never recommend it for any project.

If you don't act with honesty and justice. Eventually people will see through you and stop using your service.

Comment: -i am honestly fed up and tired of stackoverflow and will never recommend it for any project.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set up an output folder to reference your libraries in `ASP.Net core`.
The `global.json` file at root level of your solution reference your sources.

ex:

```
{
   "projects": [
      "src",
      "test",
      "integration"
   ],
   "sdk": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
      "architecture": "x64"
   }
}
```

The `projects` section lists folders containing the source code.
On each folder and subfolder declared in this section the build process will look for a `project.json`.

If you want to reference a project of a `classic class library`, Visual Studio will create a wrap `project.json` in the `wrap` folder at the root level of your solution and add this folder to your `global.json`.

This `project.json` file defines paths to your classic class library :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "net40": {
      "wrappedProject": "../../ClassicClassLibrary/ClassicClassLibrary.csproj",
      "bin": {
        "assembly": "../../ClassicClassLibrary/obj/{configuration}/ClassicClassLibrary.dll",
        "pdb": "../../ClassicClassLibrary/obj/{configuration}/ClassicClassLibrary.pdb"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `global.json` file becomes:

```
{
  "projects": [
    "src",
    "test",
    "integration",
    "wrap"
  ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update1",
    "architecture": "x64"
  }
}
```

Comment: -Thanks @agua. I will test it in the morning. This looks like exactly the answer i was looking for. Incidentally a number of other developer seem to be having problems with third party libraries not been installed correctly. This could potentially solve a number of problems.